# Android RelativeLayout issue

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a RelativeLayout with two nested RelativeLayouts. I want first RL to stay on top and second to be scrollable, but this does not work.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--Buttons-->
  </RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <!--Lots of nested RelatiLayouts with Views-->
    </RelativeLayout> 
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for code inserts just paste it, mark the code and push the "{ }" button above

Comment: Why are you nesting relative layouts? With all of the attributes that are available for Views inside of a RelativeLayout you should be able to get just about any desired outcome that you are trying to using only 1. I can understand that if you want part of your UI to scroll and not another part then you'll need another Layout as a child of the ScrollView. But beyond that I believe you could get the same output without nesting so many Layouts. You should look into LinearLayout if you are wanting to design your UI this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an xml attribute you need to know for that `android:layout_below`

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeTop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <!--Buttons-->
  </RelativeLayout>
  <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeTop"> <!-- here it goes! -->
    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <!--Lots of nested RelatiLayouts with Views-->
    </RelativeLayout> 
  </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

An alternative is LinearLayout which works great for there layouts as it can "divide" your layout into the two parts...